# File association and thumbnail preview in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, thumbnails, file-association

I have created an application and associated on registry a file extension on Windows 10, so when you double click a file associated with my extension, it opens my app with the file as parameter.

Now, I want the files associated to my application to behave in Windows 10 just like images - I mean, having a thumbnail preview, so when the user selects "large icons", he would be able to see a preview of the file.

I wonder how can I do it. What kind of metadata my file should have so Windows would recognize it and show a preview. Of course, I don't want just large icons, I want a file preview just like image files.

It isn't hard for me to generate a preview bitmap and integrate it to the file format I created (or even to change the file format completely, since I didn't publish anything yet), but how would windows recognize it? Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm afraid there is not a method for you to set thumbnail for a StorageFile in UWP.

Comment: How about icon handlers? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144122(v=vs.85).aspx I'm going to check if it works as I need...

Comment: Jayden Gu, I found an open-source project that does exacly what I need: https://svgextension.codeplex.com/ As soon as I`m able to reproduce it, I'll answer my own question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some research, I found a sample code that does exactly what I need. It creates a thumbnail provider, which have access to the file's contents (binary), and then I can use it to generate the thumbnail of the file.

The sample that creates a IThumbnailProvider can be found here:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CppShellExtThumbnailHandler-32399b35/view/SourceCode#content

The project should generate a dll, that we should register on Windows. It might be done using the following lines:

```
system32/regsvr32 ThumbnailProviderx64.dll
syswow64/regsvr32 ThumbnailProviderx86.dll
```

unregistering is like this:

```
system32/regsvr32 /u ThumbnailProviderx64.dll
syswow64/regsvr32 /u ThumbnailProviderx86.dll
```

Another nice sample could be found at:
http://www.codemonkeycodes.com/2010/01/11/ithumbnailprovider-re-visited/